# Djangoのデータベース設定について

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

[DjangoGirlsTutorial](https://djangogirlsjapan.gitbooks.io/workshop_tutorialjp/content/)を進めていたのですが、データベースのあたりでエラーが出てしまいます。
具体的には、[クエリセット1のページ](https://djangogirlsjapan.gitbooks.io/workshop_tutorialjp/content/django_orm/)でコンソール画面を開いてデータベースのデータを表示させようとした時に以下のエラーが出ました。

```
$ python manage.py shell
/Users/you_mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:724: UserWarning: Attempting 
to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install 
IPython inside the virtualenv.
  warn("Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, 
please "
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov  1 2016, 17:50:43)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from blog.models import Post
In [2]: Post.objects.all()

Out[2]: ---------------------------------------------------------------
ImproperlyConfigured                  Traceback (most recent call last)

…

/Users/you_mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py in complain(*args, **kwargs)
     19
     20 def complain(*args, **kwargs):
---> 21     raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is 
improperly configured. "
     22                     "Please supply the ENGINE value. Check "
     23                     "settings documentation for more details.")

ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. 
Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more 
details.
```

mysite/setting.pyのデータベース設定はチュートリアルと同じく以下のようにしています。

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

エラーを見る限り、sqlite3を正しく起動できていないように思います。どのようにすればデータベースを読み込むようにできますでしょうか。
解決方法がありましたら、ご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysite/setting.pyのデータベース設定はチュートリアルと同じく以下のようにしています。

正しくは `mysite/settings.py` ではないでしょうか？（末尾のsが抜けている)
もし、質問上の記載間違いで、settings.pyに正しく設定できている場合、以下の内容を確認してみてください。

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.DATABASES)
```

これで、Djangoがどのsettingsファイルをどのように読み込んでいるのかが分かります。
この実行結果が、設定した値と異なっている場合、ファイルを間違えているか、settings.pyに複数設定があって後勝ちになっているか、何らかの問題があるのだと思います。

Comment: `mysite/settings.py`の記載間違いでした。誤解を生んでしまい申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: from django.conf import settings  
print(settings.DATABASES)  
>
{'default': {'PORT': '', 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 
'OPTIONS': {}, 'USER': '', 'HOST': '', 'NAME': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 
'TIME_ZONE': None, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 
'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'TEST': {'MIRROR': None, 'CHARSET': 
None, 'NAME': None, 'COLLATION': None}}}

このように表示されました。

Comment: `mysite/settings.py`の最後の行をコメントアウトしてみたら正常に動作するようになりました。

`"""`
`import dj_database_url`
`DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()`

`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

`STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'`

`DEBUG = False`

`try:`
`from .local_settings import *`
`except ImportError:`
`pass`
`"""`

Comment: 解決してよかったです。dj_database_url は標準の機能ではないので、なにかを見て書かれたのだと思いますが、そこがうまく行ってなかったんでしょうね。手を加えた部分がうまくいかない場合は、少しずつ元に戻してみて問題を切り分けて行くと良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！